# Jabber group chat history - receive all offline messages

Tags: history, jabber

I want to receive all Jabber messages that were written while I was offline, like in Skype. It's not exactly ALL messages to be honest, it's somewhat like month but it is enough.

For now I receive some of the messages, but only some.

Is this a client-side or server-side setting? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

Its a server side setting. If you run the server, there might server side logs as well.